# Execution order of anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

```
(function() {
  f();
  f = function() {
    console.log(8);
  }
})()

function f() {
  console.log(9)
}

f();
```

prints 9, 8.

Why isn't it 8, 9?

Why doesn't the anonymous function execute first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the numbers for order of execution.

Basically you have 4 parts,

1. The function declaration with a hoisted function,
2. an IIFE calling the function
3. a new assignment of `f` and
4. the last call of the new function.

```js
(function() {
  f();                 // calling hoisted function      2
  f = function() {     // assigning new function to f   3
    console.log(8);
  }
})()
function f() {         // hoisted function              1
  console.log(9)
}
f();                   // calling new function          4
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it now :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you defined `f()` after the invocation of it.
So it doesn't invoke the  `f()` function defined in the IIFE but the outter f() :

by reversing the order :

```
(function () {
    f = function () {
        console.log(8);
    }
    f();
})()
```

you could have 8 and 8 as output as in both cases it invokes the overridden `f()` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the output you can modify it like this

```
(function() {
  f();
  function f() {
    console.log(8);
  }
})()

function f() {
  console.log(9)
}

f();
```

But let me explains why it executes that way.

```
(function() {
  f(); // Line Number -a
  f = function() { //b
    console.log(8);
  }
})()

function f() { //c
  console.log(9)
}

f() //d
```

There is the difference.The line `'b'` is a function expression.It is only defined when it is reached.So when it reaches `'a'` i doesn't actually know about the 'b' function.On the contrary, `c` is a function declaration and when it encouters 'f()' it immediately knows.
Right after `'a'` is executed (which executes `'c'`,it will be modified by `'b'` to its new defanition.

To make it more clear consider this function

```
function printMe(){
  var a;
  console.log(a);
  a = 10;//It an expression
}
```

The output you would get is it is defined.Because untill that line `a=10` is not executed, it doesn't have a value.

There is this little code written by Philip Roberts which actually shows how your code is being executed .**Please have a look [here](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=KGZ1bmN0aW9uKCkgew0KICBmKCk7IC8vIExpbmUgTnVtYmVyIC1hDQogIGYgPSBmdW5jdGlvbigpIHsgLy9iDQogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coOCk7DQogIH0NCn0pKCkNCg0KZnVuY3Rpb24gZigpIHsgLy9jDQogIGNvbnNvbGUubG9nKDkpDQp9DQoNCmYoKSAvL2Q%3D!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D)**